# Inyección de clases mediante JavaScript

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un menú que al hacer scroll se pega en la parte de arriba, para hacer que se pegue tuve que hacer una clase llamada "fixed" y aplicarla al momento de bajar con el scroll.

La cuestión es que la clase "fixed" al aplicarse, no hereda el ancho o los query del contenido.

De esta manera esta normal:

```
<div class="hoja">
<ul class="pesta" id="pesta">
     <li><a href="#tab1" id="tabs"><span>Perfil</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2" id="tabs"><span>Trabajos</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3" id="tabs"><span>Contacto</span></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

y después se le agrega la clase "fixed" y "pesta", que no contienen más que esto:

```
.pesta{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.pesta {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul.pesta li {
    width: 12%;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.pesta li a {
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;    
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.hoja {
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Al incluirla queda todo bien, solo que ahora se sale del contenido y abarca el 100% viewport osea un width de 100% y por lo tanto los botones se van hasta el final.

Este es el JavaScript que utilizo:

```
 var pesta = document.getElementById('pesta');
 var altura = pesta.offsetTop;

 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset > altura){
        pesta.classList.add('fixed');
    }else{
        pesta.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
 });
```

---

Y aquí dejo una demo donde se puede ver el problema:

```js
var pesta = document.getElementById('pesta');
var altura = pesta.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > altura) {
    pesta.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    pesta.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background:#ccc;
}

.pesta {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.pesta {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul.pesta li {
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.pesta li a {
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.hoja {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  margin-bottom:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoja">
  <ul class="pesta" id="pesta">
    <li><a href="#tab1" id="tabs"><span>Perfil</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" id="tabs"><span>Trabajos</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" id="tabs"><span>Contacto</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
```

Comment: Esto parece más un error con los valores del CSS que con el JS en sí. ¿Seguro que no hay definida otra clase `.fixed` en alguna de tus hojas de estilos cuyas propiedades "pisan" las tuyas?  ¿Puedes crear un [mcve]?

Comment: Si, me imagino es con css, entonces como aria para inyectar la clase o que simplemente quedara igual y solo agregar un backgroun o que quede fija en el top

Comment: Sin ver un [mcve] del problema, no sé qué decirte. ¿Cuáles son los estilos de `#pesta` y `.pesta`?¿usas algún framework (p.e. Bootstrap)? Crea el ejemplo y seguro alguien puede ayudar

Comment: Agregue mas codigo, aver si me entiendes a si, no utilizo ningun framework

Comment: Te he creado un [mcve] en la pregunta para que la gente pueda reproducir y ver el problema.

Comment: ¿No sería tan fácil como quitar el `flex-end` cuando esté fijo? `pesta.fixed { justify-content: center; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Por qué falla**

El problema que tienes es que cuando se ponen algunos valores de posicionamiento (p.e. `absolute` o `fixed`) el elemento se saca del flujo normal de la página y su posición puede no depender de sus ancestros.

En tu caso, estás usando `position: fixed` para la clase `.fixed`. Antes de añadir la clase, `ul.pesta` tiene un ancho del 100% que se aplica sobre el 70% que tiene `.hoja`; eso hace que efectivamente `ul.pesta` tenga un ancho de un 70%. Pero al ponerle la clase `.fixed`, ese elemento se saca fuera del flujo y el 70% ya no le aplica, por lo que ocupará el 100% de la  ventana.

**Cómo podría solucionarse**

Idealmente, podrías usar el posicionamiento [`sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) en lugar de `fixed`, esto haría que el elemento se comportara de manera "normal" mientras está en la ventana, pero se comportara como `fixed` al hacer scroll y quedarse fuera de la vista (pero sin sacarlo del flujo, siempre contenido dentro del elemento padre).

De este modo, ya no hace falta tener ningún JavaScript para controlar el scroll (al menos no para el `ul.pesta`) ni añadir/quitar la clase `.fixed`. Lo que simplificaría el código un poco y se vería así:

```css
body {
  background:#ccc;
}

.pesta {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.pesta {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .5s;
}

ul.pesta li {
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.pesta li a {
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.hoja {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  margin-bottom:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoja">
  <ul class="pesta" id="pesta">
    <li><a href="#tab1" id="tabs"><span>Perfil</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" id="tabs"><span>Trabajos</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" id="tabs"><span>Contacto</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>.</p>
  <p>.</p>
  <p>.</p>
</div>
```

Lamentablemente, `sticky` no está ampliamente soportado a día de hoy y no va a funcionar en muchos navegadores. Por lo que tendrías que buscar una alternativa.

Lo que podrías hacer es definir  `.fixed` para el caso particular de `ul.pesta` (con el selector `ul.pesta.fixed`) y hacer que tenga un ancho de 70% intentando imitar los valores que tendría dentro de `.hoja` (algo que a veces puede no ser tan fácil como suena).

Una versión aproximada:

```js
var pesta = document.getElementById('pesta');
var altura = pesta.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > altura) {
    pesta.classList.add('fixed');
  } else {
    pesta.classList.remove('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  margin:0;
}

.pesta {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.pesta {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul.pesta li {
  width: 12%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.pesta li a {
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .5s;
}

ul.pesta.fixed {
  right: auto;
  left: 20px;
  width:70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hoja {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoja">
  <ul class="pesta" id="pesta">
    <li><a href="#tab1" id="tabs"><span>Perfil</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" id="tabs"><span>Trabajos</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" id="tabs"><span>Contacto</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p>.</p>
  <p>.</p>
  <p>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. :P

Comment: @Mariano correcto. No quise quitar la parte que añadía/quitaba la clase `.fixed` por si se utilizaba en otro sitio (y porque hacía que cambiara el fondo). Pero creo que sí lo voy a quitar para que no haya confusión

Comment: @Mariano OK. Quité el JavaScript y moví los estilos de `.fixed` a `.pesta`, ¿cómo se ve ahora?

Comment: Muchísimo más claro. Me gustan las respuestas que simplifican los problemas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

He modificado un poco el HTML metiendo el ul en un contenedor y ajustado CSS sin utilizar sticky

```js
var pesta = document.getElementById('pesta');
 var altura = pesta.offsetTop;

 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset > altura){
        pesta.classList.add('fixed');
    }else{
        pesta.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
 });
```

```css
.fluid-container{
  width:100%;
}
.pesta{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.pesta {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:900px;
    margin:auto;
    border:0px solid red;
    padding:0;
}

ul.pesta li {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.pesta li a {
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;    
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.hoja {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoja">
<div class="fluid-container" id="pesta">
  <ul class="pesta">
       <li><a href="#tab1" id="tabs"><span>Perfil</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab2" id="tabs"><span>Trabajos</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab3" id="tabs"><span>Contacto</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

</div>


<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
</p>
```

Espero que te valga esta versión